# Playing mp3 file with MediaElement c# asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, web, mp3

I am trying to play mp3 file (play,pause,stop) in asp.net website c# from the code behind. I didn't find anything that help me.

So here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
    media.Source = new Uri(@"\Music\demo.mp3");
    media.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
    media.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;    
    media.Play();
}
```

I am getting error red line under this line:

```
media.Play();
```

tnx for helping,

Rom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use HTML5 instead of trying to use audio encoding on the server side:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp